# How to implement a trait for tuples including the "one value tuple" in Rust?

Tags: rust

The following Rust code compiles, but how do it get the commented out impl for "one value" tuples compiled? I understand the problem, that `(u8, i32)` is as well a "one value" tuple with a tuple type, but how do I get this work here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```rust
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

trait Trait {
    fn type_ids() -> Vec<TypeId>;
}

// impl<T0> Trait for T0
// where
//     T0: Any,
// {
//     fn type_ids() -> Vec<TypeId> {
//         vec![TypeId::of::<T0>()]
//     }
// }

impl<T0, T1> Trait for (T0, T1)
where
    T0: Any,
    T1: Any,
{
    fn type_ids() -> Vec<TypeId> {
        vec![TypeId::of::<T0>(), TypeId::of::<T1>()]
    }
}
impl<T0, T1, T2> Trait for (T0, T1, T2)
where
    T0: Any,
    T1: Any,
    T2: Any,
{
    fn type_ids() -> Vec<TypeId> {
        vec![TypeId::of::<T0>(), TypeId::of::<T1>(), TypeId::of::<T2>()]
    }
}

fn main() {
    // println!("{:?}", u64::type_ids());
    println!("{:?}", <(u8, i32)>::type_ids());
    println!("{:?}", <(i32, String, f32)>::type_ids());
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'll find the answer in this crate: https://crates.io/crates/impl-trait-for-tuples ?

Comment: Are you just confused as to how to write a one-field tuple? `impl<T0> Trait for (T0,)`

Comment: @PitaJ omg, I really didn't know they exist :/. Post it as answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
impl<T0> Trait for T0
```

is the implementation for the generic type itself, not the single-field tuple.

You write a single-field tuple with parenthesis and a trailing comma like `(T,)`:

```rust
impl<T0> Trait for (T0,)
```